# MVC Json Serialisation, embedded list reordered

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, serialization

I'm hoping you can help me. I have the a fairly complex object that represents geoJson data. The class was generated by placing some of the geojson into the converter found [here](http://json2csharp.com/).

The code that is generated works fine when I'm de-serialising for conversion and storing into a database, however when I come to retrieve the data and re-serialise it I am getting some very strange behaviour.

Here is a brief snippet of my json:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection",
 "crs": {"type":"name",
         "properties":{ "name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}},
 "features":[
   {"type":"Feature",
    "properties":{"name":"AB","color":"#0E0299"},
    "geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates":[[[[56.8860559718878,-2.21295884939764],
                                 [-2.22418043724705,56.8874548172591],
                                 [56.8873756021234,-2.22608015201419],      
                                 [-2.24113736145235,56.8942204769533],
                                 [56.8953863168858,-2.24940218298088],
                                 [-2.25140561654796,56.8950015957031],
                                 [56.8950244655219,-2.25393237467251],
                                 [-2.26499735012973,56.8885090148966],
                                 [56.8827985864266,-2.28369393347917]]]]}}]}
```

Rather than putting this in twice I will explain what is wrong.
Every other entry in the coordinates list is reversed. So the second pair of values is back to front.

However when I look at the data in the original class before serialisation they are in the correct order (i.e. 56.8874... comes first then, -2.2241....)

If you put that json into the class generator I linked it basically creates the classes I'm using.

It is the following property that is resulting in the issues:

```
public List<List<List<List<double>>>> coordinates { get; set; }
```

Firstly, I think it is hideous, but that aside it makes it hard to see what exactly is going on.

My question is:

How can I maintain the order of my coordinates within my list as these coordinates represent steps along a path. By reversing every other coordinate when I plot them on my world map it jumps between two sides of the world, which is completely wrong.

If you need more information or my question isn't clear please let me know.

Comment: What serializer are you using?  Can you show your code for serialization and deserialization?

Comment: @dbc I use the standard c# mvc serializer so my code looks similar to the following return json(geoJsonObect). I can't post the exact code untill tomorrow but the geoJsonObect is the outer most object that the converter generated just renamed.

Comment: After generating classes for the JSON above, I tried deserializing and then serializing the JSON string above using Json.NET and JavaScriptSerializer -- but I could not reproduce your problem.  The X and Y coordinates were not transposed.  Can you try to make a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the bug?

Comment: @dbc I'll give it a go and let you.

Comment: Thanks.  Can't reproduce with DataContractJsonSerializer either, doing it manually with your JSON string.

Comment: @dbc, Turns out the issue wasn't in the serialisation. It was in my LINQ when I was merging various foreach loops to generate a single LINQ statement something was going haywire and re-arranging data. For the life of me I cannot see what it was but having gone back to foreach loops it is working with no issues. My initial testing had been miss leading and resulted in me making the wrong conclusion. Thanks for looking into it :-)